# insert operation in linked list code is not working

Tags: c, struct

it is a code for linked list basic insert and display operation,but after entering arguments key and info for the insert function program do not proceed i mean let us say i enter 4 as key and 5 as info there should be a node created pointed by head and when show is called my linked list with one element should be shown but it is not happening. is something wrong with insert and show function or what should i do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static struct node{
    int key, info;
    struct node *next;
};

static struct node *head, *z;

initialize()
{
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *head);
    z = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof *z);
    head->next = z;
    z->next = z;
    z->key = -1;
}

insert(int n, int info)
{
    struct node *t, *x;

    t = head;

    while (t->next != z) {
        t = t->next;
    }

    x = (struct node *)malloc (sizeof *x);
    x->key = n;
    x->next = t->next;
    t->next = x;
    x->info = info;
}

show()
{
    struct node *t = head;

    while (t->next != z) {
        t = t->next;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", t->key, t->info);
    }
}

main()
{
    initialize();
    int i, j;

    printf("enter the number and info\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &i, &j); // i is key and j is info 
    insert(i, j); // passing arguments to insert function
    show();
}
```

Comment: _progamme do not proceed_ What does that mean? You realize you never call `show()`?

Comment: Include `stdlib.h` in your code.

Comment: Compile your code with `-Wall` option to see possible warnings.

And after calling `insert()` call `show()` to see the output.

Comment: ok i get it actually i should have given the input in two different lines i.e. scanf("%d",&i) and then scanf("%d",&j).i don't know if i can give them at same time.Thank you @Ani

Comment: Check this code:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7c4855fca3037e9

Comment: 1) As @Ani posted, OP's code worked on my machine, once it had proper function return values. 2) `scanf("%d%d", &i, &j);` is fine (other than you should check the return value of `scanf()`.  It will read the numbers is they are on 2 lines of 1 on each.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`static struct node{` change to(hereafter -->) `struct node{`

`initialize()` --> `void initialize()`

`insert(int n, int info)` --> `void insert(int n, int info)`

`show()` --> `void show()`

`main()` --> `int main()` //and return 0;

[demo](http://ideone.com/K8dyd5)